# Updating a java program that runs as a daemon from within the program

Tags: java, linux, rpm, processbuilder, runtime.exec

I have a java program that currently runs under `RHEL 6` as a `daemon` on system boot. I also have a webpage GUI that allows the user to interact with the daemon for administration purposes.

One of the administration task I would like the user to have the ability to do from the GUI is to update the program.

This is done using the from within the java program by downloading the `RPM` from a website which the user enters and then installs the rpm using `rpm -Uvh` from a `processbuilder` call within the java program.

The problem is that part of the updating of the daemon requires the daemon to be stopped thus resulting in a `signal 15` error from within the daemon since it is trying to do the update from within a program that is shutting down.

I am thinking then I want to spawn from the `processbuilder` or another `fork` type tool on java, a separate process that runs the update and does not encounter a `signal 15` when stopping the daemon during the `rpm -Uvh` command.

What is the best way to generate a separate process that will not crash during the update process?